# How to achieve a cross-browser letter-spacing for the star (and other) character (if font-family that supports it is present)?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, cross-browser

I have the following text:

★ ★ ★ ★ ★

consisting of five stars. (character 9733)

I need to have it the same (or approximately same) letter-spacing in all browsers. So far I have tested it in Opera, IE9, FF8 and Chrome 16.

In IE9 and FF it looks the same, in Opera it's slightly different and Chrome is the most problematic one. See the image:

[image]

In this example CSS property letter-spacing is set to "0px". 
Is there any cross-browser way to force equally wide spaces between characters?

I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT: SELF-SOLVED

**EDIT2: Original question was edited to make it more clear what was actually the issue.

Comment: What about a [CSS shape](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)?

Comment: Convert it to a PNG on the server side and display that.

Comment: every browser has its own way to render fonts... (different font files) also they have antialaising, shadings and whatever. you can never be 100% sure that text is looking same in all browsers... use images

Comment: Can you post your code please (html and CSS) ? What is the unit of your text ? "em" or "px" ? Do you use a CSS Reset ? All the browsers native CSS must be reset. If you still have problem you will have to use conditional CSS on Chrome...

Comment: Sorry I don't have rights to comment your code. I had to post an answer to ask you question. As ComFreek said, CSS Shape can be a good solution.

Comment: I wonder how you color only 17% of the 4th star in yellow.

Comment: Thank you. I may try CSS Reset. I used "px", but this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: STM: One div with a smaller width and the same content and overflow hidden is placed on another.

Comment: Post the code. (And note that it is impossible to get exactly the same rendering on all browsers. So you should explain what you see as wrong. On Chrome, it’s apparently either the font family or the font size or both, but what did you try to get?)

Comment: As for the code, it is created dynamically, but there is really nothing special about it. But OK, I will post it.

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am well aware of the different font rendering in various browsers, but the main issue was the different letter-spacing.

I solved it with JS this way (pseudocode):

```
expectedOffsetWidth = [number of letter] * [font size in pixels];
offsetDeviation = expectedOffsetWidth - wrapperElement.offsetWidth;
wrapperElement.style.letterSpacing=Math.round([original letter spacing] + parseInt(offsetDeviation) / [font size in pixels])+"px";
```

Comment: That's odd, because your screenshot definitely shows a problem with a different font!

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't.

You may *want* it to look the same in all browsers, but you don't *need* it.

If images aren't acceptable, there exists no solution that will satisfy you, I'm afraid. Different browsers and different OS's all have different methods for rendering, different fonts available, different ideas of screen pixel density, different notions of what a color is, …

Add to that the multitude of ways in which a browser or OS can be adjusted to fit the users needs, and you are basically screwed.

If pixel-perfect display is your desire, you are in the wrong business.

Comment: Actually, it does not have to necessarily look the same in a pixel-perfect way. Letter-spacing is the most important issue. Is there a way to adjust true letter spacing (with JavaScript for example)?

Comment: Ok, it is possible with JavaScript, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with star made of css triangles. Unfortunately, with small stars, the lines are very rough in IE7.

However, to be honest, with the amount of HTML and CSS this creates, you're better off with an image/sprite.

The following HTML/CSS will generate 10px stars. You can toggle stars gray by adding the class "i". You can toggle the "active" color of stars to a dark with the "inactive" class.

```
.stars {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 54px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 12px 8px 30px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.stars b {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.stars .a {
    left: 11px;
}

.b {
    left: 22px;
}

.stars .c {
    left: 33px;
}

.stars .d {
    left: 44px;
}

.stars b b {
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 3px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff; 
    top: 8px; 
    left: 2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.stars .y {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;  
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 4px solid #005B7F;
    border-bottom: none;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0;
}

.stars.inactive .y {
    border-top: 4px solid #555;
}

.stars .i .y,
.stars.inactive .i .y {
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.stars .z { 
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;  
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #005B7F;
    border-top: none;
    left: 2px;
    top: 0;
}

.stars.inactive .z {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
}

.stars .i .z,
.stars.inactive .i .z {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
}

<span class="stars">
<b><b class=\"y\"></b><b class=\"z\"></b><b></b></b>
<b class=\"a\"><b class=\"y\"></b><b class=\"z\"></b><b></b></b>
<b class=\"b\"><b class=\"y\"></b><b class=\"z\"></b><b></b></b>
<b class=\"c i\"><b class=\"y\"></b><b class=\"z\"></b><b></b></b>
<b class=\"d i\"><b class=\"y\"></b><b class=\"z\"></b><b></b></b>
</span>
```